# Is there any format string to read Caption[2,120] data directly form a GraphicsMagick object?

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I didn't find anything in the GraphicsMagick doc about reading the caption under the Profiles object data so I don't know if it's possible at all. Any suggestion?

This is how I'm able to retrieve the EXIF data from the gm object.

```
gm(dir + '/image.jpg').identify('%[EXIF:*]', function (err, info) {
    console.log(info);
});
```

Comment: Do you mean ICPT's Caption tagging, EXIF's description tagging, or Optical Character Recognition for text that is drawing into the image raster?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you need to know. I'm using this [npmjs.com/package/gm] module to identify the metadata of an image edited on photo mechanic. If you'll go to "Custom Identify Format String" section of this module.If you'll go to "Custom Identify Format String" section of this module. You'll find a method which returns all the metadata of an image. What I need to know is the formatting string which I can use to extract just the Caption[2,120] of an image. In the above example code **'%[EXIF:*]'** formatting string returns a string of all the exif metadata of an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Caption[2, 120]` tag is part of the IPTC spec, not EXIF. With ImageMagick, the IPTC is a little different, and follows the following format.

```
%[IPTC:dataset:record]
```

So for `Caption`, the dataset is `2`, and the record is `120`.

```
%[IPTC:2:120]
```

I don't know GraphicsMagick for Node, but this should work.

```js
gm(dir + '/image.jpg').identify('%[IPTC:2:120]', function (err, info) {
    console.log(info);
});
```